# What is procedure.ini in SQL and how .ini works?

Tags: sql-server, ini

My teacher gave us a search about the procedure.ini , and .ini how it works in SQL.

I did my search on Google no result, would someone help me to understand this Procedure and .ini function? And he asked us to write a program about .ini function.

Comment: Is this related to Microsoft SQL Server? I've never heard of `procedure.ini` in the context of SQL Server and have been using the product since it was released over 20 years ago.

Comment: eh? SQL is a pretty big product but 20 years in to my career ... not something I ever heard of. You need a new teacher / to clarify what they meant.

Comment: thank you broh i really was thinking to ask another teacher about it . thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `procedure.ini` in MS SQL Server .

MS SQL Server have just `Stored Procedures` with this three types:

- User-defined Stored Procedures.
- Extended Stored Procedures.
- System Stored Procedures.

Update:

You tag `SQL Server`, but mybe you mean `Oracle` so [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22583_01/DR/help/INI_Functions.html#DALc02a_2726006080_149450) you can start.